# what would make ios::fail() evaluate to 1?

Tags: c++, linux, fstream

i am trying to open a file with

```
27   string tline;
28   ifstream finp; // input file
29   ifstream dinp; // data files
30 
31   finp.open(argv[1]);
32 
33 
34   cout << "finp.good() = " << finp.good() << endl;
35   cout << "finp.bad() = " << finp.bad() << endl;
36   cout << "finp.fail() = " << finp.fail() << endl;
```

and i end up with output

```
finp.good() = 0
finp.bad() = 0
finp.fail() = 1
```

now, i cannot find any good documentation on what would cause this other than that it is an internal logic problem. what am i supposed to do to correct this?

if it helps, i am running on linux where i need to include both `<cstring>` and `<cstdlib>` while i do not have to do this when running on OSX. could this be the problem? if so, how do i correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forgive me, i made a simple mistake. when i ported my source files over to the linux system, i had ported over a script as well. i was confusing the executable with the script and the script had a filename hardcoded into it which was not in the directory.

basically, i was accidentally trying to read a file which was not there!

Answer (score 2):

`fail()` will return 1 when you attempt a conversion and it fails. For example, if the next character in the file is something other than a digit, and you attempt to read an `int`, then the failbit will be set, and `fail()` will return 1. Any conversion attempted when you're already at the end of the file will also set the failbit.

`fail()` will also return 1 when/if the `badbit` is set. This is set to signal a serious problem with the file itself, not just an inability to read some particular piece of data from the file.